# app_remove event in Firebase

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics for my Xamarin Forms mobile app. The Firebase documentation says it can track the event "app_remove" . But I cant find that in firebase events dashboard .

Can someone help !

Comment: is this iOS or Android? What is the version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, when the app is removed by users, users can't go back to the app so that Firebase Analytics can log the app_remove event. In addition, the process is already terminated and there is no way to upload that event even if Analytics can log it. It's nearly impossible to log app_remove events on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For Android app, please note that the app should be [linked to Google Play](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038?hl=en&ref_topic=6317497) to report app_remove event on Firebase.

Comment: I have installed the app directly from the code and uninstalled the app. I got the event count for app_removal .

Comment: The documentation says: "The app_remove event counts the removal of application packages, regardless of the installation source..."

Comment: Is it possible to know who removed the app? For example maybe user_id or email?

Comment: I also want to detect who removed the android app. any idea or link for help